# Multiple videos in a tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer

I have a UITableView with multiple videos. I know that we can have only one MPMoviePlayerController in a UIView, so I went with the AVPlayer option with which I have two problems:
 1. When I change the player item for particular cell, the item is changed in all cells. I would like to have different videos in different cells. Here's my code for every cell:

```
            let urlFromParse = NSURL(string: lVideo.url!)

            var asset = AVURLAsset(URL: urlFromParse, options: nil)

            var playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

            self.moviePlayerSunday = AVPlayer.playerWithPlayerItem(playerItem) as AVPlayer

            var layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.moviePlayerSunday)

            layer.frame = cell.addVideoView.bounds

            layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

            layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

            layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true

            self.moviePlayerSunday.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.None

            cell.addVideoView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

2. My second problem is that the player doesn't have buttons for play, pause, full screen etc.

   I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Please post your cell creation code as well.

Answer (score 0):

For your first point : 
If I'm not mistaken you are using self.moviePlayerSunday to display your video. You are then using the same instance of player for all your cells. 
Instanciate a new one for each cell that needs to have its own player.

For your second point : 
AVPlayer plays videos directly. You have to create play/pause/etc.. buttons yourself

Comment: Yes, I am using the same one because when I create a new one for every cell inside cellForRowAtIndexPath metod it doesn't even show.